# ¿Como puedo hacer permanente una notificacion?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Lo que quiero es hacer que mientras la app este abierta la notificacion no se cierre, la notificacion tiene un boton al expandir que es para cerrarla.

Para que me ayuden tienen como ejemplo el código de la notificación:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //<-- La clase que se abrira al hacer click en la notificacion
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationID", notificationID);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    CharSequence ticker ="Exit";
    CharSequence contentTitle = "App Open Mode";
    CharSequence contentText = "App Notification Open Mode";

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTicker(ticker)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, ticker, pendingIntent)
            .build();



    nm.notify(notificationID, noti);
```

Yo intenté usando esto:

```
notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Pero la app se cierra y no sirve.

Comment: "Pero la app se cierra y no sirve." si cierras la aplicación que comportamiento esperas?

Comment: Dice se ha detenido, osea la app no abre. Lo que espero es que la notificacion sea permanente

Comment: En ese caso Alejandro, es muy importante en Android el uso del LogCat, revisa que mensaje te muestra( busca "Caused  by:..........), incluso puede no ser en esta parte del código.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, había una linea del codigo que no daba error pero estaba mal puesta.

Comment: Agrega tu código correcto y actualiza tu pregunta, para que sirva a otros usuarios. Entonces con notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; debe funcionar!

Comment: Si, me funciono

Answer (score 2):

Hola puedes intentar con este metodo.

```
builder.setOngoing(true);
```

saludos

Comment: esto es lo mismo que : Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

Comment: No me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer permanente y evitar desechar la notificación (dismiss), se puede realizar usando [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) definiendo la bandera [FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT) :

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

o definir :

```
notification.setOngoing(true);
```